Почему в стандарте C++ есть тип std::size_t, но нет типа std::ssize_t?
Почему в стандарте C++ есть тип std::size_t, но нет типа std::ssize_t?

https://jameshfisher.com/2017/02/22/ssize_t/

А чего закрыли-то, на вопрос можно дать объективный ответ (или какой-нибудь комитет объективно рассмотрел добавление ssize_t и по каким-то объективным причинам решил не добавлять, или не рассмотрел тоже по каким-то объективным причинам)

@andreymal проголосуйте за переоткрытие. Хотя содердимое вопроса стоило бы подредактировать

Потому что в C++ не принято возвращать -1 при возникновении ошибки. Для этого используют исключения.

Есть ptrdiff_t.
